# What does this vertical line through the F in CRLF mean?

Tags: xml, notepad++, newline, hex-editors

I am chasing down a compilation problem in a CSPROJ file (Visual Studio, C# project, an XML format) and noticed a strange display of one single `CRLF` in the file:

[image]

<sub>(this is, obviously, with the "show all characters" option turned on)</sub>

See how the second `CRLF` in the image is rendered with a thin vertical line through the `F`?

- I have closed/re-opened Notepad++, *no change*, doesn't seem to be a
  rendering glitch.
- If I delete the second `CRLF` and hit enter, *no change*, it is
  re-inserted with the same rendering.
- If I delete both `CRLFs` and then hit enter twice, *then they are both
  normal*.

I was expecting to find something different at the byte level, but a hex editor shows no differences that I can see:

[image]

`0d` is carriage return ([CR](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html)) and `0a` is a line feed ([LF](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html)).

This file is always edited on Windows 7 or 10.

The reason I even noticed this and am suspicious that it is a real problem is because I've started getting a compilation error from this block of the file which doesn't (yet) have any explanation. So I was initially wondering if a bad line ending was responsible.

Comment: That looks like a text cursor to me.

Comment: @JohnDvorak it does resemble the cursor, but is not. In NP++ you can't actually position the cursor in that location.;

Comment: The hex viewer is pretty clear that there's nothing suspicious there that could cause a compilation error, and whatever's happening must originate from Notepad++.

Comment: @JohnDvorak ... maybe this is nothing, but its odd. The fact that deleting them both and re-adding produces a different result means something is changing, at least as far as the editor is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

That vertical line might be due to a white vertical edge near columns 4 or 5. That needs two Notepad++ settings. Firstly, menu => **Settings => Style configurator => Global Styles => Edge colour => Foreground colour** to White. Second menu => **Settings => Preferences => Editing => Vertical Edge Settings** to Show vertical edge ticked, plus some combination of the other Vertical Edge fields.